# Функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть 4 функции `case1();` `case2()`; `case3()`; `case4();` и есть еще 5 функция `start();`, которая запускается по нажатию кнопки, а сама функция `start()` должна запускать `case1();` `case2()`; `case3();` `case4();`
В итоге получается так что case1 запускается, а остальные не запускаются

Comment: В функции `case1` происходит ошибка, которая прерывает выполнение кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функции `case1` происходит ошибка, которая прерывает выполнение кода.